# Reorganize QT Menu Actions from ui designer

Tags: qt, gui-designer

After some developing QT app, I need to **reorganize my QActions** in some different menus.
I know, I can do it manually through editing generated ui_mainwindow.h, but it's not the right way. (As I would need to do it every rebuild).
Is there a possible way to reorder menu actions using a designer interface?
I'm sure the answer is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a really overcomplicated the problem. I don't know why I thought that action actually deleted when deleted from menu, but it's possible to reorganize it by deleting and inserting to correct place again.

So simple.